# Preferred way to call super class's __init__ method

Tags: python

I would like to call the `__init__` method of the superclass. Here are two way I can think of:

```
super().__init__(some_arg)  # I am using Python 3

# or like this:
MyBaseClass.__init__(self, some_arg)
```

What is the preferred way of doing it?

Comment: `super()`, because `super()` does **not** necessary calls the superclass...

Answer (score 0):

```
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Perceive you don't pass the "self" - it is inserted automatically.

Super() was first designed in Python 2 to allow classes to be reused as mixins in a class hierarchy in a way that their immediate superclass may change,